# Does html textbox control automatically removes line feed and carriage returns

Tags: html, textbox

This is about the html text input control i.e.

```
<input type="text"/>
```

As we know it allows a single line to be entered.

Now, if i try to paste the below text in this control:

```
'addressLine1<some X spaces>
<some Y spaces>addressLine2'
```

it automatically converts to:

```
'addressLine1<some X spaces><some Y spaces>addressLine2'
```

Question: I see this is happening, is there a more concrete documentation or article which i can refer to.

Comment: I guess i will have to stop here : http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Refer below links

I've checked some of these, but no answer for your question, maybe you can find. Try these..

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_text.asp)

[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

[also at developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Check these